# Internal Inductance of MOSFET

Tags: datasheet, inductance

Datasheets sometimes define an internal inductance ([example here](https://rocelec.widen.net/view/pdf/fx7jagabqe/INFN-S-A0002297177-1.pdf?t.download=true&u=5oefqw)). From what I've [read](https://upcommons.upc.edu/bitstream/handle/2117/100354/Manuscript_Rev1_2016_08_31.pdf), internal inductance is defined as the inductance of the wire's flux acting on its internal cross sectional area. An image of this area is copied below for reference.

[image]

If current density is assumed to be uniform and skin effect is ignored, the inductance per unit length of a wire is \$ \frac{L_{int}}{l}=\frac{\mu}{8\pi} \$. For a relative permeability of 1, this turns out to be 0.05nH/mm, which is extremely small.

[image]

Looking at [an example Infineon datasheet](https://rocelec.widen.net/view/pdf/fx7jagabqe/INFN-S-A0002297177-1.pdf?t.download=true&u=5oefqw) copied above, the Internal Source Inductance and Internal Drain Inductance are given as 4.5 nH and 7.5 nH respectively, between the wire lead and center of the device die. This number is much greater than the theoretical internal inductance, using the given dimension of a 6mm wire lead.

Why is there such a difference between the theoretical and actual internal inductance? Is the datasheet actually referring to external self inductance, which is the portion of the wire's flux that is in the loop area of the circuit?

Answer (score 1):

The inductance is being given from 6 mm outside the package to the centre of the die. This allows you to compute the voltage between the closest practical point you can connect another component, and the die, when the current changes in that lead. This is the external inductance as you define it.

However, when calculating the total inductance between some circuit reference point and the die to compute that voltage with current change, the quoted 4.5 nH contribution is *internal* to the package. It's a minimum you can't go below, no matter how close you manage to connect your snubbing components to the device.

Comment: Thanks for your response! So the "internal inductance" given in the datasheet is actually the contribution of the lead's inductance to an external loop. I'm guessing the minimum inductance that you specified would be the contribution of each lead to the loop inductance if the terminals of the package were shorted. Essentially, it's external inductance of the minimum loop area for the package.

Comment: @Brad Not just the lead, but also the bond wire, which may be more significant considering how thin bond wires can be.

Comment: And not just inside the package. You cannot shorten the leads of a D-Pak, so the external part is also included.

Answer (score 0):

The internal inductance they are talking about is the inductance of the lead 'inside' the package. We know this because it says the inductance is:-

> Between lead, 6mm (0.25in.) from package and center of die contact

The inductance value is the *partial* inductance (ie. contribution of the lead to the loop inductance), which is what the circuit designer needs to know.

Comment: Thanks for your help! That makes sense. It must be an external inductance in that case if it contributes to loop inductance.